# Footer not showing up correctly

Tags: css, wordpress, customization, footer

I've installed an edited version of the Gridly Theme onto my test site [wordpress.jssim.com](http://wordpress.jssim.com) and then to the actual site ...

Although both theme files i uploaded are the same, the footer generated for the latter was out of place and seeming ignored the specified css styling of ".copyright-wrap". The one on my test site is the desired one.

Any ideas why my footer did not load correctly on the actual site?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The footer on your website has been commented out in the HTML code and is still included on the wordpress url.

If you uncoment this you'll find that it looks "almost" the same on both sites.

Comment: Thank you! I commented it out initially as i was running locally and did not want certain elements of the footer to show. Totally forgot about it.